# Generic type constraint does not enable assignment without explicit cast

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I can't believe in my many years of C# experience it has taken me this long to discover the following limitation, and I can't quite believe this is unavoidable, if anyone can illuminate me to the contrary I would be very pleased. Consider the following:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1;

internal class BaseClass { }

internal class DerivedClass : BaseClass { }

internal class CastingExperiment
{
    public void AssignmentAttempts<TBase>(object anyRandomThing)
        where TBase : BaseClass
    {
        BaseClass baseClass = new DerivedClass();
        TBase wantToDoThis = new BaseClass(); // Compiler says no, cannot implicitly convert type
        TBase haveToDoThis = (TBase)baseClass;
        TBase whichIsAsEvilAsThis = (TBase)anyRandomThing;
    }
}
```

I'd far sooner avoid the explicit cast in this scenario, the type constraint is right there to tell the compiler what it needs to know about the assignment compatibility but still the cast is required.

I've also tried deriving `CastingExperiment` from an interface and with either covariant or contravariant constraints for `TBase` and it still insists on the cast. Am I missing something?

Comment: What if you invoke the method like `AssignmentAttempts<DerivedClass>(...)`? That would make `TBase` -> `DerivedClass`, and you can't cast a `BaseClass` to a `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `where TBase : BaseClass` means that `TBase` can be any type that **IS** `BaseClass` - it can be `BaseClass` or any derived from it.

When you create new instance using `new BaseClass();` you should have a reference of the same type (`BaseClass`), but your reference type is `TBase` (which can be any derived type).

So when you call your method like this:

```
someInstance.AssignmentAttempts<DerivedClass>(someArg);
```

then non-working line will result in something like this:

```
DerivedClass wantToDoThis = new BaseClass(); // check the reference type
```

If you just write code this way (without generics) you'll get compile time error.

You can cast derived types to base ones, but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks that's embarrassingly clear now you (and Johnathan Barclay) have pointed out the flaw in my reasoning there. In the real production code example the instantiation of the thing I wanted to assign was coming from another method, with the type being guaranteed to be ok. In that case the cast can actually be avoided by making that other method generic and giving it the same base type constraint.